# #Deleted in MS Access front-end to a MYSQL database

Tags: mysql, vba, ms-access

I am trying to find a work-around to the #Deleted problem when adding new records in MS Access front end to a MYSQL database. I am trying to do this via this VBA:

```
Private Sub Surname_AfterUpdate()
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
Me.Refresh
 Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim pk As Long

    pk = Me.ID
    Me.Requery
    Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone
    rs.FindFirst "[ID]=" & pk
    Me.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark
    Set rs = Nothing



End Sub
```

With this I am trying to get the present ID, store it as bookmark, save and refresh and go back to the ID bookmarked.

However, it is as if VBA cannot find the ID because it is not yet transmitted to the database and so I am getting an error like 'invalid use of null.'

I also tried adding TIMESTAMP etc to no success - still getting #Deleted ...

Pls help.

thanks

Elton

Comment: in the form after insert event you could try this command me.recordSource = me.recourdSource this has the same effect as me.requery. sort the query that last entry shows as first in this way your new entry is always at top?

Answer (score 0):

Create a PassThrough Query in Access,

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

This will be able to get the last inserted ID, which you can use to refer to the record. Hope this helps.